# SharedPreference for different users on Android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, persistent-storage

Is this possible?

Think of the following scenario.

- User A logs into device and fires up your app, doesn't like certain features, so turns them off.
- Profile is switched to User B.  They fire up the app and love all the features that user A didn't like, so they switch them all on.

Is there a way that the profile can be switched back to User A and all the features that user wanted are still switched off? (And on when user B uses the device)........?

The reason I ask is because I'm using local flags to determine if a user has unlocked (Google Play Games) achievements, so if the user reaches the goal, the flag is set like so:

```
if (!score100_AchievementUnlocked)
    if (score>=100){        
    unlockAchievement(Score100);
    score100_AchievementUnlocked=true; //Don't check this any more
 }
```

I'm then saving score100_AchievementUnlocked in sharedPreferences so that we don't keep sending API requests to Google Play Games when we no longer need to.

However, if another user then comes along and plays the game, as things stand, they will never be able to unlock the achievement because the app will never check it (as score100_AchievementUnlocked will be true).

So I'm wondering if I can detect who is the active user on a device and have them use their own sharedPreferences.

Comment: instead of `score100_AchievementUnlocked` use profile specific names? `score100_AchievementUnlocked_ProfileA`

Comment: Thanks @JemshitIskenderov, how would I achieve that?  I mean how do I know which user is currently on the device so I can use name-specific boolean flags?

Comment: If you use Google profile for storing achievements, then try to use that as Profile

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean @JemshitIskenderov, perhaps you could provide an example?  Thanks again. All I'm currently doing is using Google Play Games achievements.  Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean `SharedPreferences appPrefsA = context.getSharedPreferences("A", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` and `SharedPreferences appPrefsB = context.getSharedPreferences("B", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make profile system into your application.

Just concatenate username and every preference to use them as the key for Sharedpreference system.

Then, let the user choose theirs favorite profile to retrieve theirs configuration for the application according to the chosen profile.

Please let me know if you get the idea, hope it help or if you need more information.

Sincerly yours.

Comment: Thanks @jeronev an example would be appreciated.  Like I say, it's  important that the flags I mention in the question are at least different for different people who log into Play Games, otherwise, a user who plays the game after another user has unlocked an achievement will never be able to unlock the same achievement because the *local* (device) flag will be set such that the code never checks the achievement again.

Comment: So you want to share user configuration outside the device itself ? I didn't mentionned anything about using achievement system from google play. So you want to share data (ie user's configuration) though network ? You could use database and storage solution.